# Can't get mouseover to work in xCharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm learning how to use xCharts for my website on PHP and have been following the examples to learn how to do different types of charts. The only thing that does not work for me is the mouseover and mouseout functions. I've been using this example code:

```
            var tt = document.createElement('div'),
            leftOffset = -(~~$('html').css('padding-left').replace('px', '') + ~~$('body').css('margin-left').replace('px', '')),
              topOffset = -32;
            tt.className = 'ex-tooltip';
            document.body.appendChild(tt);

            var data = {
              "xScale": "time",
              "yScale": "linear",
              "main": [
                {
                  "className": ".pizza",
                  "data": [
                    {
                      "x": "2012-11-05",
                      "y": 6
                    },
                    {
                      "x": "2012-11-06",
                      "y": 6
                    },
                    {
                      "x": "2012-11-07",
                      "y": 8
                    },
                    {
                      "x": "2012-11-08",
                      "y": 3
                    },
                    {
                      "x": "2012-11-09",
                      "y": 4
                    },
                    {
                      "x": "2012-11-10",
                      "y": 9
                    },
                    {
                      "x": "2012-11-11",
                      "y": 6
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            };
            var opts = {
              "dataFormatX": function (x) { return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse(x); },
              "tickFormatX": function (x) { return d3.time.format('%A')(x); },
              "mouseover": function (d, i) {
                var pos = $(this).offset();
                $(tt).text(d3.time.format('%A')(d.x) + ': ' + d.y)
                  .show();
              },
              "mouseout": function (x) {
                $(tt).hide();
              }
            };
            var myChart = new xChart('line-dotted', data, '#myChart', opts);
```

Just to be clear, the charts IS being created and data is correct, the only thing missing is the mouseover, which should work according to the example. Any ideas why this is not working? Any thing I'm missing?

Comment: Does the console show any error?

Comment: There are no errors from XChart when anything goes wrong. The basic example works but the examples showing the mouseovers do not work, and you end up with a blank screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the css for .ex-tooltip, if you inspect the example you'll see:

```
.ex-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background: #EEE;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    border-collapse: separate;
    display: none;
}
```